Why did moderator delete my question, without writing any reason?
Someone closed my question as off topic, "not appear to be about the Latin Language, within the scope defined in the help center”. Then moderator deleted it, see screen shot below. Why?


This answer addresses both the question as presented and also a longer pattern.
Your question matches the pattern of a user who is no longer welcome to participate on this site in any way but who still keeps trying to get back with new accounts.
It is a waste of time for moderators or others to try to genuinely engage with posts of said pattern, so our policy has become to shoot them down without warning.
This includes closing questions, deleting accounts, and such.
It is of course possible that a new account posting a similar question does not belong to the banned person.
But as long as the question shows patterns that predict very bad outcomes with very high probability, we will act on it.
The question you linked to was very poor, and having it closed and deleted does not count as collateral damage even if you are not the banned person.
To get a question through, study what it is that makes a good question.
Read highly voted questions, read meta discussions, read help pages.
And, from experience, do not ask about etymology or prefixes.
Those topics are apparently very difficult to ask about, so you should start with other topics.
Trying the same thing over and over again only makes it harder to succeed one day.
If you have had several of your accounts suspended or deleted in the past, do not come back.
If not, read the previous paragraph very carefully before trying again.

For those of us following along at home who aren't familiar with the referenced user [and who can't see the deleted question], would you mind giving a little more context on what exactly the issue is/was?

@Basic Without getting too much into the details at the moment, this is a problem user across multiple sites, and at one point was banned from all of StackExchange. And yet that user continually tried to evade the ban. Once the ban expired, they went straight back into making the same kinds of question that were originally unwelcome here with no sign of improvement or learning.

See also this question which bears all the hallmarks of the original user in question.
